# Android - PDF header signature not found

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am trying to show the generated pdf to user. I am using iText to generate pdf. I have created the pdf. Now I want to view the pdf. I am trying to convert the pdf to image and show to user.

```
public void makeImageFromPDF() throws DocumentException, IOException {

        String INPUTFILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/iText/sample.pdf";

        String OUTPUTFILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/iText/sample1.pdf";

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE));
        document.open();
        System.out.println("............1");
        System.out.println("............INPUTFILE==> "+INPUTFILE);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);
        System.out.println("............2");
        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfImportedPage page;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);

            byteArray = reader.getPageContent(1);
        }
        document.close();

    }
```

But I am receiving run time error `PDF header signature not found`.

I got his error at this line .`PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);`.

Please let me know how to resolve this problem. And let me any other way to view the pdf.

```
04-04 09:24:29.326: W/System.err(12102): java.io.IOException: PDF header signature not found.
04-04 09:24:29.326: W/System.err(12102):    at com.iText.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.checkPdfHeader(PRTokeniser.java:201)
04-04 09:24:29.326: W/System.err(12102):    at com.iText.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:490)
04-04 09:24:29.326: W/System.err(12102):    at com.iText.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:165)
04-04 09:24:29.337: W/System.err(12102):    at com.iText.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:154)
04-04 09:24:29.337: W/System.err(12102):    at com.example.MainActivity.makeImageFromPDF(MainActivity.java:283)
04-04 09:24:29.337: W/System.err(12102):    at com.example.MainActivity.NewDesingTest(MainActivity.java:262)
04-04 09:24:29.337: W/System.err(12102):    at com.example.MainActivity.createNewPdf(MainActivity.java:131)
04-04 09:24:29.337: W/System.err(12102):    at com.example.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:81)
04-04 09:24:29.337: W/System.err(12102):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-04 09:24:29.337: W/System.err(12102):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-04 09:24:29.347: W/System.err(12102):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-04 09:24:29.356: W/System.err(12102):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-04 09:24:29.356: W/System.err(12102):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 09:24:29.356: W/System.err(12102):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-04 09:24:29.367: W/System.err(12102):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 09:24:29.376: W/System.err(12102):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 09:24:29.376: W/System.err(12102):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-04 09:24:29.386: W/System.err(12102):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-04 09:24:29.386: W/System.err(12102):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where did you find a library with package names `com.iText`? That is most certainly not an official version of iText. Please let us know where you downloaded it.

Comment: Hi.. Still now I am using `lowagie`.. But before two days you said this is out dated. That's y I just replace the `lowagie` with iText in note pad for post here.

Comment: How would replacing `lowagie` with `iText` make it less outdated?

Comment: Actually original `at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.checkPdfHeader(PRTokeniser.java:201)` I just edit the logcat for post here.

Comment: Even when your a newbie, you should never act as one. In any case: you are trying to do something that is impossible with iText.

Comment: Sorry Sir.. So, can I conclude myself that **Can not view PDF using iText**..

Comment: iText is **NOT** a PDF viewer. It doesn't render PDF to the screen. It doesn't render PDF to an image. This is commonly known.

Comment: Ok Sir.. Thanks for the clarification..!! I will try to find any other way to view the pdf..!! Thanks again Sir..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing a filename to the Document constructor, so its creating a new document with no info in it.  So it has no header.  And if you're reading in a pdf file to convert it to an image, you shouldn't need a pdf writer at all.  Your code is just really confused.

Get rid of the Document and all mentions of PdfWriter.  Just do the parts with PdfReader

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Can you explain me with a simple sample Plz???

Comment: This answer is wrong. iText does not convert PDF to images, hence the code in the question can never work.

Comment: Then please let me any idea to view the pdf plz..